# product of transversal is a transversal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $K \leq H \leq G$ where $G$ is a group, $[G:H]$ is finite and suppose that $T$ is a transversal of $K$ in $H$ and $U$ a transversal of $H$ in $G$.

Show that $TU$ is a transversal of $K$ in $G$.

Is this correct to say that for $t \in T, u \in U$ we have $uHtK$. Then knowing that $e\in H$,$uetK=utK$ and thus $TU$ is a transversal of $K$ in $G$.

Comment: Shouldn't $T$ be a transversal of $K$ in $H$?

Comment: @Shaun yes that's right. Fixed !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify if you mean *right* or *left* transversals (you are actually mixing them up). Anyway, if $T$ is a left transversal for $K$ in $H$ and $U$ is a left transversal for $H$ in $G$, then $UT$ is a left transversal for $K$ in $G$.

First of all, $G=\{utK: u \in U, t \in T\}$: take $g \in G$, then $g=uh$ for some $u \in U, h \in H$. And $h=tk$, for some $t \in T, k \in K$. Hence $g=utk$.

Uniqueness: assume $utK=u't'K$, with $u,u' \in U, t,t' \in T$, then $ut=u't'k$ for some $k \in K$ and hence $u=u'(t'kt^{-1}) \in u'H$. So $uH=u'H$, implying $u=u'$ (definition transversal!) and this implies at its turn $t=t'$ by the same argument.

**Note** if $U$ and $T$ would be *right* transversals, then $TU$ is a right transversal for $K$ in $G$.

Comment: @Milten, yes will change, thank you so much.

Comment: Why $u′(t′kt−1)\in u′H$

Comment: @Ethan Kharitonov This is because $t', k, t^{-1} \in H$. Remember that as a set $T \subseteq H$, and of course $K \subseteq H$.